# Strange value while converting long into int

Tags: java

Please, explain to me, why do I get longToInt value == -9 when converting long into int? I understand that my long is higher than max value of int and I expected to get some warning by IDE or some error by compiler, not -9. Thx!

```java
long someLong = 21474836471L;
int longToInt = (int) someLong;
System.out.println(longToInt);
```

Comment: You drop the first three bits of the `long` with your cast. `System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n", Long.toBinaryString(21474836471L), Integer.toBinaryString((int) 21474836471L));`

Comment: re *expected ... some error in compiler* --  you explicitly told the compiler that you understood and expected the result, by writing the cast `(int)`.  Writing that turned off the warning that you otherwise would get.